# Modifying queryset in changelist_view on Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I need to modify the final queryset used by the changelist in the django admin.

I believe (correct me if I'm wrong) I can achieve this by overriding changelist_view(), but trying to change the queryset doesn't work, just original queryset loads in the admin.

```py
def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
    response = super().changelist_view(
        request,
        extra_context=extra_context,
    )

    try:
        qs = response.context_data['cl'].queryset
    except (AttributeError, KeyError):
        return response

    response.context_data['cl'].queryset = qs.filter(pk__in=qs.order_by().values('pk').distinct('target'))

    return response
```

I thought that changing the context data for the changelist would achieve this, but it didn't work.

How can I do this, note I need to modify the final queryset after all other filters have been applied.

Comment: Maybe the method you're looking to override is the `get_queryset` in your ModelAdmin class instead of the changelist_view? Inside that method you can change the queryset

Comment: `get_queryset` returns the original queryset, `response.context_data['cl'].queryset` is the queryset after all admin filters have already been applied, I need to modify the queryset after all the admin filters have been applied.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import YourModel

class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  def get_queryset(self, request):
      qs = super().get_queryset(request)

      if hasattr(self, 'in_change_view') and self.in_change_view:
          # Apply the queryset filtering for change_view
        return qs.filter(some_field=some_value)
      else:
        # Apply the queryset filtering for changelist_view
        return qs.filter(another_field=another_value)

def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
    self.in_change_view = True
    response = super().change_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
    self.in_change_view = False
    return response
```